# L.Control propagate event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I create custom handler by extending L.Handler and add handler for map click event in addHooks method. From outer code, I`m add handler for click event, too. I use L.DomEvent.stop(e) in custom handler, but event propagate and outer code handle it. It seems like a bug.

```js
const map = L.map("map", {
      boxZoom: false
    }).setView([39.50, -98.35], 5);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

L.CustomHandler = L.Handler.extend({

      initialize: function(map) {
        this._map = map;
      },

      addHooks: function() {
        this._map
          .on('click', this._onMapClick, this)
      },
      
      _onMapClick: function(e) {
        L.DomEvent.stop(e.originalEvent);
        console.log('map click from handler');
      },

      removeHooks: function() {
        this._map
          .off('click', this._onMapClick, this);
      },

    });
    
map.addHandler('customHandler', L.CustomHandler);

map.customHandler.enable();

map.on('click', (e) => console.log('map click'));
```

See my plunker pls https://plnkr.co/edit/yuh67rrsOZYSpUjXam4g?p=preview